# playback is very low with avaudio

Tags: ios, xcode, avaudioplayer

I have record and playback routines. see code below.  The only problem is that the playback on my device is very low. The volume is okay on the simulator and I have the device volume all of the way up. Is there something else I need to set.
Here's the record code:

```
NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:


                            [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                               @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                               nil];
    NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

    // Setup audio session
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

    // Define the recorder setting
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    // Initiate and prepare the recorder
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:NULL];
    recorder.delegate = self;
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
[recorder record];
```

And the playback:

```
 player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url error:nil];
        [player setDelegate:self];
        player.meteringEnabled = YES;

        player.volume = 1.0;
        [player play];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your speaker default as there is some time problem audio go througg other routes

```
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:&sessionError];
```

Try `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` mode it has high volume when you play your sound

```
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&setCategoryError];
```

Comment: Sending it to speaker works. The second one "ambient" does not work. thanks for the help.